# Codeigniter controller method 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I cloned a copy of Codeigniter from github today using this link: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter.git. I am currently running MAMP setup so that http://localhost:8888 points to my htdocs folder.  My root folder is called 'time'. When I go to http://localhost:8888/time/index.php, I do see the Codeigniter welcome page.  Also, I can go tohttp://localhost:8888/time/ and see the same welcome page, even though I don't have an .htaccess file in the root directory.

Here is the problem.  I added the following function to the Welcome.php controller class:

```
public function test()
{
    echo 'Test';
}
```

This should display a page which shows 'test' when I visit  http://localhost:8888/time/index.php/test.  However, I get a 404 page not found error.  Does anyone have any suggestions for understanding and fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `localhost/index.php/test` doesn't refer to the method test in the welcome controller. You would have to go to `localhost/index.php/welcome/test` or use routes.

They way you are doing it implies there is a controller named `Test.php` and it is trying to go to the `index()` function of that controller.